# error in setting of android in sdk and gradle to run cordova comand in ionic

Tags: ionic4

I’m setting up a new apk in ionic and want to run app in mobile to release apk 
. This is windows

`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined` (recommended setting)

`ANDROID_HOME=D:\sdk` (DEPRECATED)

Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cordova version >= 7 or Android SDK Tools >= 26 you need to manually install gradle ([reference](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11591)). On Windows you can install gradle like this:

1. Download the binary release from https://gradle.org/releases/
2. Unzip it to any folder you like, for example `C:\gradle`
3. Edit your system environment variables to include the directory `C:\gradle\bin` (where `gradle.bat` is located`)

Afterwards you should be able to build your project normally.